# Trying to build a local Docker file,: failed to create shim task:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

WORKDIR /admin-flask

COPY . /admin-flask

# set environment variables
# ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV FLASK_APP run.py

VOLUME . /var/wwww

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

RUN apt autoremove -y

RUN apt install python3 -y && apt install python3-pip -y 

RUN pip install virtualenv

RUN virtualenv env

RUN chmod +x run.py  

# install python dependencies
RUN /admin-flask/env/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

# gunicorn
#CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "run:app"]
CMD  ["/admin-flask/env/bin/gunicorn","--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "run.py"]
```

> ```
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container
> ```
>
> init: open /dev/ptmx: no such file or directory: unknown.
> ERRO[0004] error waiting for container:

Trying to build a local Docker file, getting  this error when running a container

Comment: What specific command are you running that produces the error?  If you're getting the error from a specific line in the Dockerfile, which one?  Do you need the entire Dockerfile as you've shown it to cause the error, or can some of it be removed?

Comment: error log is empty, it isn't showing any specific error, i am getting this while while running container `docker run -it --name admin-server admin-serve` @DavidMaze

Comment: even  if dockefile has errors, not sure which one, because file is building comfortably